# Why getting a Syntax error in MySQL Trigger query?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have learned the triggers in Oracle SQL, and not that well versed in MySQL. I was trying to convert a trigger command from Oracle to MySQL. First of all, I am not able to find the `when` statement, I found the `if else` instead. This is what I wrote:

```
create trigger overdraft 
after update on account
for each row 
begin
    if account.balance < 0 then
        insert into borrower(select customer_name, account_number from depositor where new.account_number=depositor.account_number);
        insert into loan(select new.account_number, new.branch_name, new.balance);
        update account set balance = 0 where account.account_number = new.account_number;
    end if;
end;
```

But I am getting three syntax errors, first at end of first insert statement at the left parenthesis saying, "Statement is incomplete, expecting : ','". Other two are on each of the `end`s saying "end is not valid at this position: Expecting BEGIN, EOF,....". What is wrong with me code? I am having hard time figuring out.

Comment: In mysql you cannot action the table which fired the trigger - in this case account. You can adjust the NEW. values in a before trigger. You need to rethink your approach

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Delimiter like this.

I thought that you had tested all the insert.
Inser ino mus be like the example wthat i written,but the columnnames **could differ**.

As i described you can't use the same table in your trigger  that fired the trigger. so use the set paramter to change the balance to 0

```
DELIMItER //
create trigger overdraft 
after update on account
for each row 
begin
    if account.balance < 0 then
        insert into borrower (customer_name, account_number) select customer_name, account_number from depositor
         where new.account_number=depositor.account_number;
        insert into loan (account_number, branch_name, balance) select new.account_number, new.branch_name, new.balance;
        set new.balance = 0;
    end if;
end;
DELIMItER ;
```

Comment: In mysql you cannot action the table which fired the trigger

Comment: P. Salmon is right you can not update the account table, because this would fire aggain the trigger witch would end in an eternal loop

Answer (score 0):

There are several things.  `delimiter` probably being one of them:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger overdraft before update on account
for each row 
begin
    if new.balance < 0 then
        insert into borrower (customer_name, account_number)  -- column list here
            select d.customer_name, d.account_number
            from depositor d
            where new.account_number = d.account_number;

        insert into loan (account_number, branch_name, balance)  -- column list here
            select new.account_number, new.branch_name, new.balance;

        set new.balance = 0;
    end if;
end;$$

delimiter ;
```

Notes:

- `delimiter` is needed so the definition of the trigger does not end at the first semi-colon.
- The reference in the initial `if` (`account.balance`) is not understood, because `account` is not defined.
- You want to update the balance in the row with the trigger.  Hence, you want a *before update* trigger, not an *after update* trigger.
- When inserting rows into a table, you should always list the columns being inserted.  I have speculated on the column names above.